# Dynamically Create Nested Structure

Tags: dynamic-programming, abap, rtts

I have a table which has the following fields, and suppose it holds the following three entries:

| Node | Field | Level | Data Object | Field | Value | Table_struct_indicator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| - | Field1 | 0 | EQUI | EQURN | - | struct |
| Node1 | Field2 | 1 | EQUI | ERDAT | 20241903 | struct |
| Node1 | Field3 | 1 | EQUI | uname | - | struct |

I basically want to create a structure which now has the following format:

```
types: begin of node1,
         field2 type char200,
         field3 type char200,
       end of node1.
types: begin of xyz,
         field1 type char200,
         node1  type node1,
       end of xyz.
```

This structure could be as deep as possible and could also include tables.

I didn't find anything yet to create a dynamic table which has no real ABAP data definition behind it, most of the things I found just used the `cl_abap_structdescr` class to describe the structure of already existing tables and then throwing those components into a field catalog, which also doesn't really help me because I need a deep structure, which as per my understanding is not accomplishable with a field catalog since it is not possible to create deep structures in field catalogs.

Comment: can you reformat the question? Plain text is hard to understand here, also context what language/db are you using etc.

Comment: @ifiht I reformatted for Shadowlight

Comment: You can create whatever kind of variable dynamically, but I don't get your question. Please ask a precise question for which there should be basically only one possible answer (as opinionated answers are not permitted).

Comment: Final note: `cl_abap_structdescr` is part of ABAP Run Time Type Services (RTTS) and can create any kind of ABAP structure dynamically, with anything inside (deep or whatever). What you call "field catalog" is an ALV concept. RTTS don't need ALV. Maybe ALV uses RTTS for some features. I just know `cl_alv_table_create` (which doesn't use RTTS) and is usually not needed (and not recommended for some reasons I could answer if the question is asked separately).